# Changing mysql database to query mysqli db?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

the following code in a php file works when querying a mysql database. However it cannot find the database when the php file is trying to connect to a mysqli database. How can I change the below code to get it to work?

Thanks.

```
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $sql = "SELECT filename FROM prefix_media_videos ORDER BY filename ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $var = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $var[] = $row['filename'];
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_query($sql)` to `mysqli_query($db,$sql)` and `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_array` while making sure your DB connection is also `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first enable mysqli extension in your php. then you can use mysqli like this:

```
 $db = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "dbName");
    if($db->connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . 
              $db->connect_errno . "<br>";
    }else{

    $query = "SELECT filename FROM prefix_media_videos ORDER BY filename ASC";
    $result = $db->query($query); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $var[] = $row['filename'];
    } 
    }
```

mysqli is related to php not to database.

Comment: for extension see what RCNeil has told.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Set up your MySQLi extension:

```
$host = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$dbName = ""; // FILL THESE IN

$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbName);
if($db->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . 
          $db->connect_errno . "<br>";
} // CHECK TO MAKE SURE IT CONNECTS
```

Then run your query -

```
$query = "SELECT filename FROM prefix_media_videos ORDER BY filename ASC";
$result = $db->query($query); 
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     $var[] = $row->filename;
}
```

[MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) is a PHP extension.  Not a database.